# How to calculate item in pivot in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, calculation

I am trying to calculate an item within a pivot in pandas but currently getting an error. I have a table that has four columns (date, country_paymentn, Payment_count and status). In the column status there are three possible categories (Paid, Rejected and Failed). I am trying to do the following calculation which is attempting to calculate the payment count for the following condition:

auth_rate = Paid/(Paid + Rejected + Failed)*100

This is the method I have tried but does not work:

```
authorisation['authorisation_rate'] = authorisation.loc[authorisation['STATUS'] == 'PAID'] / ([authorisation.loc[authorisation['STATUS']=='PAID']]+[authorisation.loc[authorisation['STATUS']=='REJECTED']]+[authorisation.loc[authorisation['STATUS']=='FAILED']]) *100
```

I have the following code for pivot which gives me the correct values for payment count in a pivot but I need the auth_rate in the values rather than the raw payment_count:

```
auth_pivot = authorisation.pivot_table(
        index=['country_paymentn', 'STATUS'], 
         columns='Date', 
         values='PAYMENT_COUNT', aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Here is an example of the type of data I am working with:
[example of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkmZc.png)

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Can you include a sample of your dataframe in your question to help you?

Comment: @Ank I have uploaded an example of the data